# One fix for all IE6 problems

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Is there a one fix solution for all IE6 problems? One HTC/jQuery file that fixes IE6 problems like PNG, background position, hover, (even) rounded corners...

I'm just too tired to look for all fixes, test them and put them in separately.

Comment: Just ignore the fact that IE6 exists and all your problems will disappear!   :-)

Comment: one fix solution? yes, use chrome.

Comment: Try to convince your client, whoever that is, to not support IE6. "Not even YouTube supports it and they have millions of visitors every day!" :)

Comment: There's always http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/05/02/quick-humor-advance-one-line-css-for-ie-lovers-worth-watching/

Comment: * html body * { zoom: 1;} ...I've been tempted to use this, but it still won't cover everything

Comment: Voting to close, as the category of "all IE6 problems" changes depending on the developer, the project, and what IE6 is being compared to. There's no comprehensive way to make an old browser act like a modern browser without forcing the end user to upgrade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't listen to people who say to you stop supporting IE6.
I prefer not to enable all features for IE6, as it will requires infinite time.

Just make sure that your website [degrades gracefully](http://www.z-oc.com/blog/2007/06/internet-explorer-deserves-graceful-degradation-but-nothing-more/).

If your website doesn't work at all in IE6, you will lose [several internet users](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Msieshare1). Specially for websites targeting [Aunt Marge](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Biculturalism.html).

The script which [vise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773464/one-fix-for-all-ie6-problems/2773491#2773491) proposed is nice one.

Don't forget to see [Universal internet explorer 6 css](http://forabeautifulweb.com/blog/about/universal_internet_explorer_6_css/).

Comment: I think I will use the IE8.js script. Heck, how do I add link?
http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: IE6 market share worldwide is not always representative. If you're site gets 90% traffic from US, then why would you care what browsers Chinese people use (IE6 - 55%). The way to go is to **measure** and **consider**. If your site gets less than 5% IE6 traffic, than your audience is "good enough" to force the rest to change their browsers. Or install Chrome Frame. A lot of people forget that it even exists. In fact it may be our only hope because we soon will be facing the IE 8 problem.

Comment: According to the same chart, it's down to 10% one year later.

Answer (score 77):

The one fix for all IE6 problems is to stop supporting IE6.

Comment: This is one of the rare flip responses that I think it actually useful.

Comment: Seconded, but poor dude might be caught in an untenable position.  Sympathy to questioner.

Comment: http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/slide51.jpg :#

Comment: man, I should have posted my comment as an answer. +19 rep! Well. +20 now!

Comment: This is Flame wars! Try to say this to you client!

Comment: How curious.  One flip answer nets two badges and +200 rep in under an hour!  I'll have to do this more often.  ;-)

Answer (score 18):

Not exactly 100% but [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) works pretty well.

Comment: Its a great script, and a perfect example of how the platform (as a whole, including all versions) is pretty shafted. I don't get how chrome, ff etc can constantly be throwing out new versions without breaking anything, and IE seems to introduce yet more issues on every iteration. Just crazy. I wonder how much this browser costs the industry per year..

Comment: chrome and safari follows standards pretty well. FF trys to follow standards..but they DO break old layouts sometimes.

Comment: Not that often though. They both have a comprehensive test suite to track down regressions. Webkit has over 10000 tests IIRC.

Answer (score 6):

http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Don't worry too much about IE6; aslong as it looks *acceptable*, then you're golden.

The web can't move on if designers and developers won't.

Comment: actually this website doesn't look the same on every website :D

Answer (score 5):

[Google Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe).

Comment: ...is no longer available.

Answer (score 4):

Alas, no.

Comment: When I tried a response "In short, no." SO told me it was too short. How did you go shorter?

Comment: Looks like the magic of `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
<sub>(source: [webdeveloperjuice.com](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/msie-trash-sign-preview.jpg))</sub>

But seriously. [IE7.js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ie7-js) mixed with [DD_Roundies.js](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/) should get you alot of places.

Someone should port webkit to javascript+canvas. That would be golden!

Answer (score 2):

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;http://www.google.com/chrome" />`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an abstraction, [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) can do a lot of things for you. It still supports IE6, so it often includes a workaround - sometimes JavaScript based - for that browser. As long as you use GWT widgets and layouts, this happens automatically, so you don't have to make changes to your code for IE6. (Of course, it can't do things that are impossible in IE6.)

You would have to be willing to make the jump to GWT's programming paradigm of course (which I personally find great, but that depends mostly on the question, if you like Java or not). However, you can use [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) to write a lot of the code in JQuery style (pretty much the same syntax and it's even a bit faster).

Answer (score 1):

I second the call to stop supporting IE6.  While it may still have non-negligible market share, this is probably pure inertia.  I highly doubt such a browser has a loyal fanbase that loves IE6 and won't change even if you make it easy for them to get something better, such as by offering a download link to IE7 or Firefox.  An equal marketshare of dedicated fans, though, would be worth supporting to avoid alienating them and their browser choices.

Comment: The only remaining problem are companies who have IE6 deployed, and make it impossible for their staff to install a real browser.

Comment: @chris_l:  These kinds of companies are probably dinosaurs that live off gov't bailouts, resist any and all change, and couldn't innovate their way out of a paper bag.  I don't feel sorry for them.  I also don't feel sorry for any staff that can't figure out how to install a "real" browser anyhow.

Comment: What about the staff that could be fired for installing software, or those whose PCs are locked down? If business users are an important part of your target market you are a fool to ignore IE6.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny:  If you work for that crappy a company, you probably won't for long b/c they'll be bankrupt soon.  If they're that backwards and resistant to change, they probably don't have any money to spend on whatever's offered on your website.

Answer (score 1):

Many many internet cafe in the "garden city" using Windows XP and IE6

Ultimate IE6 Cheatsheet: How To Fix 25+ Internet Explorer 6 Bugs
http://www.virtuosimedia.com/tutorials/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs